# How to use React js in blade template

Tags: laravel, reactjs, view, laravel-blade

I would like to use React js as a front-end for my laravel project . So i did the preset with:

```
php artisan preset react
```

Now i would like to know, how react component should be implemented in my blade views so they can access data passed to those views via controllers...

For exemple, in my homeController i pass some data:

```
return views('theview')->with('datas',$datas);
```

In theview.blade.php i can access them like this:

```
{{ $datas }}
```

but how can i use this to update react component?

Comment: passing that datas as property of react component.

Comment: like 
`@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <example-component datas={{ $datas }}></example-component>
@endsection`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of this way you pass data from laravel controller to react component.
A React Component interact with view id element `document.getElementById('example')` on your laravel viewpage.
Your **Laravel Controller** like.

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
      $data = [
        'john', 'doe'
      ];
      return view('welcome')->with('data', json_encode($data));
   }
}
```

Make sure you passing data controller to view as json. Your **Blade View**

```
   ..
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" data='{{ $data }}'></div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Your **Example Component** in reources/assets/js/components/Example.js like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      console.log('data from component', JSON.parse(this.props.data));
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <div className="container">
            .....
          </div>
      );
  }
}  

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
   var data = document.getElementById('example').getAttribute('data');
   ReactDOM.render(<Example data={data} />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

Make sure, when you change of Example.js Component code then you must run **`npm run dev`** command on your command prompt.

Comment: but why data as to be passed as json , can you tell me please ?

Comment: Because a HTML tag attribute hold only string as a value.
  `<div id="example" data='{{$data}}'></div>`

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: It woud have been better to refer to the YouTube vid for that particular example.               https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Un3DbIvqPoA

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass some server-side string/array/collection/whatever to your JavaScript

In above situation You can use Package `PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer`
this package is maintained by reputed site `laracasts` so you don't have to much worry about bugs and side effects.

Here is simple example after successful installation and boot up package.

```
use JavaScript; // declare name space.

// Class method 
public function index()
{
    JavaScript::put([ 
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'user' => User::first(),
        'age' => 29
    ]);

    return View::make('hello');
}
```

Using the code above, you'll now be able to access `foo`, `user`, and `age` from your **JavaScript**.

```
console.log(foo); // bar
console.log(user); // User Obj
console.log(age); // 29
```

For more visit: [PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)